# readline() result in pyserial python 2 and 3 compatibility

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pyserial

I am writing a simple code to communicate with several identical RS-232 devices using pyserial. I send a command and get a reply. The 6th element in the reply is my ID. This ID is used to define which device I am talking to.

I want to have a more elegant syntax that extracts the 6th element as an integer in both Python 3 and Python 2. Is there a more elegant way then just write two different functions that I call depending on which Python is used.

In case of Python 3

```
>>> port = Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial4')
>>> port.baudrate = 9600
>>> port.timeout = 0.4
>>> port.write(b"/1?80\r")
6
>>> reply = port.readline()
>>> reply
b'\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'
>>> reply[6]
52
>>> chr(reply[6])
'4'
>>> int(chr(reply[6]))
4
```

In case of Python 2

```
>>> port = Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial4')
>>> port.baudrate = 9600
>>> port.timeout = 0.4
>>> port.write(b"/1?80\r")
6
>>> reply = port.readline()
>>> reply
'\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'
>>> reply[6]
'4'
>>> int(reply[6])
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `port.readline()` is binary data (called `str` in Python 2, `bytes` in Pyton 3). So the question is how to handle binary data in a Python 2 and Python 3 compatible way. There are multiple ways to do that. The following three solutions all give the same result (number = 52) for Python 2 and 3.

**FOR BINARY DATA**

**Solution 1**

If you know how the data is encoded, you could properly decode it. This would result in a "unicode text string" (called `unicode` in Python 2, `str` in Python 3).

```py
reply = b'\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'
decoded_reply = reply.decode('latin-1')
number = ord(decoded_reply[6])
```

**Solution 2**

A more general solution would be to use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to decode binary data:

```py
import struct

reply = b'\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'
number = struct.unpack('B', reply[6:7])[0]
```

**Solution 3**

You could also use the [`six`](https://pypi.org/project/six/) module:

> Six is a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library. It provides utility functions for smoothing over the differences between the Python versions with the goal of writing Python code that is compatible on both Python versions. See the documentation for more information on what is provided.

For example:

```py
import six

reply = b'\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'
number = six.byte2int(reply[6:7])
```

Note that this library provides solutions for many other compatibility issues as well. So if you're writing a larger application that needs to be Python 2 and 3 compatible, it's certainly worth looking into it.

**FOR ASCII DATA**

If your ID is an ASCII-coded number in the range 0-9, the following solution would be the best. Using `struct` makes no sense in that case.

```py
reply = '\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'  # input in Python 2
reply = b'\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'  # input in Python 3
number = int(reply.decode('latin-1')[6])
# or if your reply is mixed binary and ASCII and you're only interested in byte 6:
number = int(reply[6:7].decode('ascii'))
```

Number would be 4 in both Python 2 and 3.

Alternatively, you could use one of the "binary" solutions and subtract 48 (=ASCII character '0') from the result.

(All examples above were tested with Python 2.7 and 3.7)

Comment: Thank you for 3 potential solutions. However, only the first one works in both Python 2 where the readline() returns a string and in Python 3 where the reply is bytes. Solution 3 in Python 3: IIn [25]: six.byte2int(b'\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'[6:7])                               
Out[25]: 52; Solution 2 in Python2: In [8]: struct.unpack('B','\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'[6:7])   
Out[8]: (52,) ; Solution 1 in Python 2: In [9]: '\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'.decode('latin-1')[6]
Out[9]: u'4' Solution 1 in Python 3:In [26]: b'\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'.decode('latin-1')[6]                             
Out[26]: '4'

Comment: Edited later: So all 3 will work but it doesn't look nice. For example, The Solution #3 becomes: Python 3: In [31]: int(chr(six.byte2int(b[6:7])    ))                                     
Out[31]: 4 and Python 2: In [13]: int(chr(six.byte2int('\xff/0`ZA4\x03\r\n'[6:7]))) 
Out[13]: 4

Comment: @Valentyn, I don't understand what you mean. I've tested all three examples above with Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 (in Python 2.7 you could write `'\xff..'` instead of `b'\xff..'` to exactly match the reply that you got, but the result is the same). In your last example you effectively do `int(chr(52))`, which is 4. Why do you do that? I can't test the code with the real `pyserial` module, but given the `reply` as specified in your question, in all three solutions the variable `number` will get the value 52 in Python 2 and 3. Wasn't that the expected result? Do you want it to return 4 instead?

Comment: @Valentyn, I've updated my answer. Please let me know if this is what you were expecting.